# Divergence of $e_{i+1}\leftarrow e_i - x_i e_i$ for Cauchy $x_i$

Tags: probability, convergence, random-walk, cauchy-distribution

Suppose $e_0=1$ and $e_k$ evolves according to the following recurrence with $x_i\sim \operatorname{Cauchy}$, IID draws from standard Cauchy random variable.
$$e_{i+1}\leftarrow e_i - a (x_i e_i)$$

Does this random walk converge to 0 in probability for any value of $a$?

This appears to be true for Gaussian $x_i$ and $0<a<\frac{2}{3}$

---

Original question for multivariate Cauchy:

Suppose I apply the following iteration on $e\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with some $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ and entries of $x_i$ IID Cauchy distributed.

$$e_{i+1}\leftarrow e_i-\alpha x_i\langle x_i, e_i\rangle$$

This is the equation for the error $e$ after one step of the [LMS filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter).
It appears to diverge to infinity for every values of $d\ge 1$ and $\alpha\ne 0$, any tips how to show this rigorously?

[image]

Related discussion for Gaussian data is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443200/7655), where we have $\alpha_1>0$ ensuring convergence to 0 in probability and $\alpha_2>0$ producing convergence to 0 in expectation, with $\alpha_1\approx \alpha_2$ for $d>1000$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/stats-cauchy-divergence.nb)

Comment: Do you sample $x$ at each iteration or only once at the beginning and apply the same $x$ each time?

Comment: Sample new $x$ at each step

Comment: Sorry it was unclear, editing

Comment: I updated my answer, which I think should be a bit more helpful.

Comment: @mhdadk you have a difference of two terms, both are unbounded, I don't think that's enough to get divergence

Comment: How is diverging defined here?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus by diverging I mean "does not converge". By "converge" I mean that for each $\epsilon,\delta>0$ there's $t$ such that $\forall i>t, P(e_i>\epsilon)<\delta$ (convergence in probability?)

Comment: how does it appear diverging? I mean how do you establish that it is diverging for Cauchy?

Comment: @Aksakal divergence was eventually proved here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836214/when-does-prod-i-1-alpha-x-i22-oversetp-rightarrow-0-for-some-alph/4838822#4838822

Answer (score 3):

Given the initial iterates $e_0 \in \mathbb R^d$ and $x_0$, rewrite the iteration as
\begin{align}
e_{k+1} &= e_k - \alpha x_k\langle x_k, e_k\rangle \\
&= e_k - \alpha x_k (x_k^T e_k) \\
&= e_k - \alpha (x_k x_k^T) e_k \\
&= [I - \alpha (x_k x_k^T)]e_k \\
&= A_ke_k
\end{align}
where $A_k = I - \alpha (x_k x_k^T)$. To show that the sequence $b_k = E[e_k^Te_k]$ diverges, it is sufficient to show that $b_1 = E[e_1^Te_1] = E[e_0^TA_0^TA_0e_0]$ is unbounded. First, note that
$$
\begin{align}
E[e_0^TA_0^TA_0e_0] &= E[e_0^T(I - \alpha (x_0 x_0^T))^T(I - \alpha (x_k x_k^T))e_0] \\
&= E[e_0^T(I - 2\alpha (x_0 x_0^T) + \alpha^2 (x_0 x_0^T)(x_0 x_0^T))e_0] \\
&= E[e_0^Te_0 - 2\alpha (e_0^Tx_0 x_0^Te_0) + \alpha^2 e_0^T(x_0 x_0^T)(x_0 x_0^T)e_0] \\
&= e_0^Te_0 - 2\alpha (e_0^TE[x_0 x_0^T]e_0) + \alpha^2 e_0^TE[(x_0 x_0^T)(x_0 x_0^T)]e_0
\end{align}
$$
Because $E[x_0 x_0^T]$ is unbounded (infinite), then $b_1$ is unbounded, and so $b_k$ diverges.

Comment: For $d=1$ this iteration converges to $0$ both in probability and expectation if $\alpha^{-1}>\frac{E[x^4]}{2E[x^2]}$. You can use that to find convergent $\alpha$ for Gaussian $x$ or fixed $x$, but for Cauchy these moments are undefined

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the "eigenvalues of $A$" part. Fixed this.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov also, I think that because these moments are undefined for Cauchy, I don't think it will be able to converge in expectation, since $E[x_kx_k^T]$ will be infinite.

Comment: Probably also need to consider behavior of $E[e_k e_k^T]$ rather than $e_k$. If you end up with errors going alternating between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, on average you have "converged to 0", but in reality you have not.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I can probably try to write up a more detailed answer later.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $E[e_k]=\pm\infty$ then,
   $E[e_{k+1}] = E[e_k - ax_k e_k] = \pm\infty.$
2. $E[e_1] = E[e_0 -a x_0 e_0] = \pm\infty$ so $E[e_k] =\pm\infty$.

Comment: The expected value of the Cauchy is undefined. It is not equal to infinity. Its variance is equal to infinity. In general, when infinities with opposite sign emerge, the result is undefined.

Comment: Above, the notation $\pm \infty$ simply means that $E[X^+], E[X^-]$ both are infinite which, according to the most common definition, is the same thing as not existing (or being undefined). The variance does not exist.

Comment: So, you are saying that "being undefined" is equivalent to "diverging"?

Comment: The usual definition is that if both $E[X^+], E[X^-]$ are infinite then the integral does not exist. The second moment of a Cauchy variable $E[X^2] = \infty$ since $E[X^-]$ is finite. But, that is not true for the variance so $V[X]$ does not exist.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the variance, you were right about that. I was asking about how exactly are you using the 1st moment in your answer. It is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

The Cauchy distro takes two parameters, so for the sake of convenience let's assume $x_0,x_1,...\underset{iid}{\sim}Cauchy(\mu,\gamma)$.

The first member of the series is $e_0$ which is given somehow (you say $e_0=1$). The next members are

$$e_1=e_0-ax_0e_0=e_0(1-ax_0)\\
e_2=e_1-ax_1e_1=e_1(1-ax_1)=e_0(1-ax_0)(1-ax_1)\\
e_3=e_0(1-ax_0)e_0(1-ax_0)(1-ax_2)\\ \vdots$$

From [Cauchy distro transformation properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Transformation_properties) we get that if $x\sim Cauchy(\mu,\gamma)$ then $(\alpha x+\beta)\sim Cauchy(\mu\alpha+\beta,\gamma|\alpha|)$. That is, we can denote the series of variables $z_0,z_1,...$ with $z_i=1-ax_i$. That is, $z_i\sim Cauchy(1-a\mu, a\gamma)$ is a series of Cauchy RVs and we can write the original series members (for $i>0$) as

$$e_i=e_0\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}z_i$$

Now, as the $z_i$ RVs are iid, we can write $$E[e_i]=e_0E\left[\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}z_i\right]=e_0E[z_0]E\left[\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}z_i\right]$$

but as $z_0$ is a Cauchy RV, its mean diverges (the same applies for all multiplicands) and therefore under $e_0\ne0, a\ne 0$ we get that $e_i$ diverges. The distro of the product itself is defined [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313709).

Comment: I don't think the proof works -- I could use the same steps for Gaussian distribution, in which case it can be shown it converges for $a<2.41\ldots$. In other words, the product of Gaussian RVs can converge to deterministic RV centered at 0, the question is what happens with a product of Cauchy RVs

Comment: Well, as you can see I take no assumptions on the size of $a$ except $a\ne 0$ (which is trivial, otherwise the problem is degenerate). The point in this proof is the divergence of the individual Cauchy RV, which causes the whole product to diverge with the single (given) condition of $a\ne 0$, not even using the given info regarding $e_0$. 

True, you could make a similar maneuver with other types of RVs, but: (a) it requires additional conditions which are not used here, and (b) it does not make this proof incorrect.

Comment: You can't factor out $E[z_0]$, because it is undefined for Cauchy R.V. Your reduction simplifies the problem to the following -- does the random walk with $i$th step being $\log x_i$ converge to 0 in probability in the limit of steps?

Comment: OK, looks like the missing trick is the formula for expectation of log of Cauchy variable, detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836214/when-does-prod-i-1-alpha-x-i22-oversetp-rightarrow-0-for-some-alph/4838822#4838822)

Answer (score -1):

Let's make this a bit complex.

Given the premises, and **a)** using the $n$-family of symbols for the index, **b)** setting $Z \equiv 1-aX$, and **c)** denoting $s$ the sign function, $s\in \{-1,1\}$ (we ignore the zero-probability event of an exactly zero realization) we arrive at

$$e_n = \prod_{k=1}^ns_k|Z_k|$$

Taking logarithms, using $I\{\}$ for the indicator function, using $i$ for the imaginary unit, and also $e^{i\pi} = -1$, we get,

$$\ln e_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln|Z_k| + \sum_{k=1}^n i\pi I\{Z_k<0\}. $$

Taking the expected value of this complex random variable, and using the i.i.d assumption
$$E[\ln e_n] = n\cdot E\big[\ln|Z|\big] + i\cdot \Big(n\pi\Pr[Z<0]\Big).$$

Assuming that the expected value exists, and since the probability does exist, this represents a sequence of complex numbers. Such a sequence converges (possibly to $\pm \infty$) if both the real part and the imaginary part converges.

The imaginary part $n\pi\Pr[Z<0]$ converges to $+ \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

As for the real part, it depends: if $E\big[\ln|Z_k|\big] > 0$ it will also go to plus infinity, in which case we could say that the complex sequence converges to $+\infty$ and establish divergence from zero. But if $E\big[\ln|Z_k|\big] < 0$ then the real part will go to *minus* infinity, and then this approach cannot deliver.

**The standard Cauchy case**

If $X$ is standard Cauchy (zero location, unitary scale), then, **[accepting this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4838667/87400)**, we have for $Z = 1-aX$,
$$E\big[\ln|Z|\big] = \ln \left(\sqrt{1+a^2}\right) >0 \quad {\rm for}\; a\neq 0.$$

So, the logic goes, if the expected value of $\ln e_n$ converges to plus infinity, so does the expected value of $e_n$, hence divergence away from zero appears to hold.

The value of $a$ should matter as regards the speed at which we can see this happening through simulations. Indicatively for a single simulation,

setting $a=1/64$:

For $n=100,000$, I obtained $e_n = 4.04433904152482\cdot 10^{-24}$ (that would indicate convergence to zero).

But for $n=500,000$ I obtained $e_n = 2.61198936024454\cdot 10^{18}$.

But this was just a single instance of simulation. Given that $Z$ is also Cauchy, its heavy tails may create a very erratic behavior.

Comment: Btw Mathematica can compute expectation symbolically and gives me exact 0

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Which expectation?

Comment: expected value of log of cauchy squared

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov  $E[\log (X^2)]$, where $X$ is standard Cauchy?

Comment: `Expectation[Log[x^2], x \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[]]` returns 0

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov If the above command refers to the standard Cauchy, then it is correct, implying $E[\log |X|] =0$ also. But it holds only for the standard Cauchy. In the case we examine the core variable is $Z=1-aX$, which is also Cauchy but not with zero location and unitary scale, so $E[\log|1-aX|] \neq 0$.